# How to select the most recent data from dataframe for a pair of keys?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in Spark/Scala world, and I have a question regarding data selection from dataframes.
I have a table with the following data, and I need to choose for each **cust** and **user_id** pair, all the last modified records, with max **modify_time**:

Original data frame:

```
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  cust  | user_id  | another_id |     modify_time    | 
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|   cust1|   1      |         222|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust1|   1      |         111|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust2|   2      |         111|2017-03-21 07:29    |
|   cust1|   1      |         333|2017-03-21 07:29    |
|   cust2|   2      |         444|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust2|   2      |         333|2017-03-22 07:29    |
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

The required result:

```
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|  cust  | user_id  | another_id |     modify_time    | 
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
|   cust1|   1      |         222|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust1|   1      |         111|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust2|   2      |         444|2017-03-22 07:29    |
|   cust2|   2      |         333|2017-03-22 07:29    |
+--------+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it gave me the expected result:

```
val custUserModifyTime = df
      .groupBy($"cust", $"user_id").agg(max($"modify_time")).collect()

 val mostRecent: Seq[DataFrame] = custUserModifyTime.map(x => df.select("*")
      .where("cust = '" + x.getAs[String]("cust") + "'" +
        " AND user_id = '" + x.getAs[String]("user_id") + "'" +
        " AND modify_time = '" + x.getAs[Timestamp]("max(modify_time)") + "'"))

val unifiedMostUpdatedData = mostRecent.reduce((a, b) => a.union(b))
```